# Calculate if a given input falls into a given value range

Tags: java

I have this code that I need to return an index based on the given `Double distance` input:

```java
public static int calculateHashPrecision(Double reference) {
    double[][] ranges = {
        {0.037, 0.018},
        {0.149, 0.149},
        {1.19, 0.6},
        {4.47, 4.78},
        {38.2, 19.1},
        {152.8, 152.8},
        {1200, 610},
        {4900, 4900},
        {39000, 19500},
        {156000, 156000},
        {1251000, 625000},
        {5004000, 5004000},
    };
    return 6;
  }
```

Say the value of `reference` passed is `1000` so it falls into the `1200, 610` range, so this function should return index 6. **What would be the best implementation for this function?**

**UPDATE:**
And if it is not in the specific *hard-coded* range, it would return the nearest one.

Comment: Are you guaranteed that ranges are not overlapping?

Comment: best? that depends on who answers. More important, what have you tried... we want you algorithm ;-)

Answer (score 2):

With for each loop you can do more quickly and fast

```
    int index = 0;
    for(double[] range: ranges){
        if( range[1] < reference && reference < range[0]){
           return index;
        }
        index ++;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static int calculateHashPrecision(Double reference) {
double[][] ranges = {
    {0.037, 0.018},
    {0.149, 0.149},
    {1.19, 0.6},
    {4.47, 4.78},
    {38.2, 19.1},
    {152.8, 152.8},
    {1200, 610},
    {4900, 4900},
    {39000, 19500},
    {156000, 156000},
    {1251000, 625000},
    {5004000, 5004000},
};
int maxValueIndexInRaw = 0;
int minValueIndexInRaw = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < ranges.length; i++) {
    if (reference >=ranges[i][minValueIndexInRaw] && reference <= ranges[i][maxValueIndexInRaw] ) {
      return i;
    }
}
return -1;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int calculateHashPrecision(double reference) {
    double[][] ranges = {
        {0.037, 0.018},
        {0.149, 0.149},
        {1.19, 0.6},
        {4.47, 4.78},
        {38.2, 19.1},
        {152.8, 152.8},
        {1200, 610},
        {4900, 4900},
        {39000, 19500},
        {156000, 156000},
        {1251000, 625000},
        {5004000, 5004000},
    };
    // search through the array of ranges, and return the first index it falls into
    for (int i = 0; i < ranges.length; i++) {
        double[] rng = ranges[i];
        // ranges as given have the higher number first, lower number second
        // adjust this logic as necessary
        double rng_bottom = rng[1];
        double rng_top = rng[0];
        if (rng_bottom < reference && reference < rng_top) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    // if no range contains the reference, e.g. for the number 6000, then return -1
    return -1;
}
```

You may want to carefully examine your ranges to make sure they're coded correctly. Did you mean for half of them to have the same start and end?

Comment: the complexity is O(n) if the entered number is last say in worst case

Answer (score 0):

If the data is sorted you can use binary search

```
    int hi = ranges.length - 1, lo = 0;
    while (lo <= hi) {
      int mid = lo + (hi - lo) / 2;
      int cmp = Double.compare(ranges[mid][0], reference);
      if (cmp > 0 || cmp == 0) {
        if (ranges[mid][1] <= reference) return mid;
        else hi = mid - 1;
      } else if (cmp < 0) {
        lo = mid + 1;
      }
    }
    return -1;
```